# Hide List item based on colum choice and time passed?

Tags: 2013, list, status

I have a SharePoint list. I also have a column called 'Status'.

I want to be able to hide the list item when `Status = closed` and 60 days have passed from the point Status is changed.

Please help me.

Comment: Be aware that the list item will not be hidden from Search unless you change the list item permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to modify your list view:

In your list view, you could set a filter that states "Show the items when column 'Status' is equal to 'Open' (and whatever options you have other than 'Closed').

As far as the time passed issue is concerned, the filter could be set to the Created column as well - something along the lines of when Created is greater than ([today]+60).

Yet another way to approach the time situation is to create a new calculated column that isn't visible in the view that holds the value of the 'Time Passed' column + 60.  You can then go to your list view and set the filter for something along the lines of - when NewColumn is less than ([today])...

[UPDATE]

Based on your revision, the concept for your solution remains the same (somewhat). The new column (as stated in the end of my answer above) would still be a calculated column, but would hold the value of:
    =IF(Status="Closed",TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"),IF(ISBLANK(Status),"","NULL"))

or something similar. Then have the filter refer just as I stated above

Comment: Ok that will work. However, how do I also factor in the 60 days?

Comment: Just edited the answer to reflect the time factor.

Comment: Im sorry. I just edited the question to better reflect what i need.

Comment: Based on your revision, the concept for your solution remains the same (somewhat).  The new column (as stated in the end of my answer above) would still be a calculated column, but would hold the value of =IF(Status="Closed",TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mm"),IF(ISBLANK(Status),"","NULL")), or something similar.  Then have the filter refer just as I stated above.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using SharePoint list view filters.

Create a new view or use existing view and add filters:

```
Status is not equal to Closed. 
AND
Created is greater than or equal to [Today]-60
```

**Reference**:

1. [Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9).
2. [Use filtering to modify a SharePoint view](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4).

Comment: Try this and let me know it works for you or not.

Comment: thank you for your answer; however, i just made an edit to the question to better reflect what I need.